# hive convert columns into a row

Tags: hive

Here is the data i have in hive:

**customers**

```
 id |  name
 ---+-------
 1  |  n1
 2  |  n2
```

**orders**

```
oid | cid | amt
----+-----+----
 1  |  1  | 10
 2  |  1  | 20
 3  |  1  | 30
 4  |  2  | 10
```

I would like to get something like this:

cid, avg(amt), oid1,oid2,oid3...etc

in other words i want each `custid`, avg of amt and all the order ids associated with `cid` in 1 row.

I have come up with something like this:

```
select c.id,avg(o.amt),.... from customers c join orders o on c.id = o.cid;
```

can some one please fill up how to achieve this please.

Answer (score 1):

It would be difficult to have a column for each order id (I am assuming that there will be a varying number of orders for each customer) but you could collect them to an array and make it its own column.  Also, you said you want `custid`, `avg_amt`, and all the orders; since this doesn't include `name` you don't need to join `customers` to `orders`.

**Query**

```
select cid
       ,AVG(amt) as avg_amt
       ,collect_list(oid) as orders_array
from customers
group by cid;
```

**Output**

```
1    20    [1,2,3]
2    10    [4]
```